# In PowerPoint, is there a way to create a printable version of an animated slide?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a presentation that has some moving parts. When printing, it of course shows the parts in their initial state. Is there a way to store a slide that would just show up when printing, not during a presentation, that has arrows that indicate the animated movement?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide slides from the “Slide Show” tab or the “Slide Sorter” view.  By default, slide show presentations skip hidden slides.

Comment: Is there a way to do the reverse: hide slides by default from the printer?

Comment: Well, it’s a bit labor-intensive, but you could create a Custom Slide Show containing only the slides you want to print, and then print that slide show.