# How to print PowerPoint 2010 slides after animation?

Tags: pdf, printing, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, animation

I have an animation on a couple of slides in my PowerPoint 2010 presentation. I would like to print the slides in the "post-animation form" (i.e. in the state the slide finishes when the animation is done) but instead I am getting an "initial-state" for each object on the slide. Is there a way to either print or save-to-PDF the slides in the post-animated form, except for removing the animation?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Related: PDF from animated slide: http://superuser.com/questions/602209/create-a-pdf-from-powerpoint-with-animations

Comment: Related: printable version of animated slides: http://superuser.com/questions/493632/in-powerpoint-is-there-a-way-to-create-a-printable-version-of-an-animated-slide